# How can i validate date (only current date or after) in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, date, simpledateformat

I need to add input validation for Dates entered by users. There is a startDate and endDate. The startDate needs to be current date or later. The endDate needs to be equal to OR after the startDate.

The date format i am using is YYYY-MM-dd

Already validating that the date is a proper date

In the request class we currently are using javax.validation like this:

```
@Pattern(regex = CommmonRegexp.DATE, message = "INVALID_FIELD")
```

How do i edit this to fit my needed constraints?

What i need: validate input for both dates making sure startDate only accepts current date or later, and endDate accepts only dates later than startDate

Comment: Since you tagged your question simpledateformat, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. And since your format is the default ISO 8601 for a `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), use that class, and you don’t need any explicit formatter.

Comment: you can check a string representing a date for boundaries in dates with a regexp, but any regexp that does it well is far from the scope of a book on regexps.  And the same happens to numbers.  Better parse the date with `SimpleDateFormat`, then check for boundaries with proper methods.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `java.time` to operate on dates in java. Following is a working method to validate the date as you require. You can change the format as you require. There are a bunch of other useful methods that you can use.
call this method as `validateDates("2019-03-03","2019-04-03")`

```
public static boolean validateDates(String start, String end) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(start, dateFormat);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(end, dateFormat);
        LocalDate current = LocalDate.now();
        return (startDate.isEqual(current) || startDate.isAfter(current)) && endDate.isAfter(startDate);
    }catch(DateTimeParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use predefined or custom `DateTimeFormatter`s as per your need. You can go through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) JavaDoc for details on DateTimeFormatters in detail and through [this blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-datetimeformatter) for examples.

[This](https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/working-with-time-zones-in-java-8-zoneddatetime-zoneid-tutorial-with-examples/) and [this](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/add-a-timezone-to-localdatetime-with-zoneddatetime-in-java-8) are some good-reads about how to use zone-ids with date-times.

Comment: No need for that explicit `DateTimeFormatter`. The input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. Those standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings. Shorten to `LocalDate.parse( start )`.

Comment: I suggest adding a note about time zone affecting the determination of current date. Your code implicitly draws upon the JVM’s current default time zone with your call to `LocalDate.now()`. I recommend always passing the optional `ZoneId` argument: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )`.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your suggestions. Thanks @BasilBourque.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like the java 8's LocalDate class rather than regex. It has plenty of helper methods to do what you are looking for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should be more than just a link. You should have some explanation, and where appropriate, some code examples.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate the feedback. Thanks.

Comment: The suggestion is good, thank you, only as @BasilBourque said, not really enough for a Stack Overflow answer. You may want to post is as a comment instead if you don’t think it has been covered in the other answer.